# EKAlarm Retrieving in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ekeventkit

Now i am working on `calendar` application that uses `EKAlarm`.I successfully save alarm time to EKEvent.When I retrieve alarm array i got like this in console

> `("EKAlarm <0x10d110b0> {triggerInterval = -86400.000000}")`

.I want to get `86400` from this array.How this possible?Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

first of all import math library like  `#import<math.h>`

then `NSLog(@"the round is %d",abs(-86400.000000));`

you can pass your objectatindex  as a parameter to abs function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EKAlarm *alerm=[[[remindArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]alarms]objectAtIndex:0] ;

 float triggerInterval =[alerm relativeOffset];
```